# Excel color cells based on each column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, colors

I'm coloring a worksheet.

For example,

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 1.33 |
| 1.7 | 1.12 |
| 1.1 | 1.07 |
| 1.0 | 1.22 |

Put dark blue on the largest one (1.7 in first column, 1.33 in second column), light blue on the smallest one(1.0 in first column, 1.07 in second column), and a gradient color in the middle according to the order.

My worksheet is a large table with more than 2000 columns and more than 2000 rows.

What I want is that each column has its own rules, not the largest dark blue in the entire worksheet, but each individual column, for example, the largest dark blue in Value1, the largest dark blue in Value2, so that analogy.

If I select the entire worksheet, add a new rule, and select the three-color rule, it will become a rule for the entire sheet.

I can select and add one column at a time, but I have over 2000 rows...that's too time consuming.

Is there any good way for me to do it quickly please? thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can select one column and then use Conditional Formatting --> Color Scales. In that dialogue you can select the top and bottom colors and letting Excel gradiate the colors between these. Repeat this for each column if you want different color scales for the columns

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74796862/apply-the-same-formatting-rule-to-each-column-independently-in-excel?noredirect=1#comment132006286_74796862