# Apply the same formatting rule to each column independently in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to use Excel to do some data visualization. What I want to do is apply the formatting rule that will use a 3-color scale based on the selected values to each column, independently. So far I've been able to do that by selecting each column manually and applying the rule, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in one go. For example, here is a screenshot of the data after I've manually done the formatting on each column. The rule was to apply a 3-color scale on the cell values in the column with lowest value in red, intermediate in yellow and highest in green (I also highlighted in blue the Top 1 value for better visibility). [image]

Comment: I guess as long as you don't use the same values on all selected columns it will not be possible. If you use the same values for the change of color for all, you select all the columns, apply the rule and then edit the rule for your desired colors and values. Otherwise, you can create several custom rules. For each color one rule.

Comment: Yes I would like to use the same color values for all the columns. However, if I select all the columns (that is to say, all the data) and apply the rule, it will be applied over all the cell values, which won't give me the desired result I think. I'll update my question with a screenshot for clarification.

Comment: It looks correct to me. The biggest values are blue, the smallest are red.

Comment: Yes, the formatting is correct, what I wanted to know is how to do it for all the data in one go, rather than selecting a column, applying the rule, and doing that over again for each column in my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to understand structure of your table without example, but you can use parameters for each column:
[image]

Keep in mind that if your parameters goes from left to right, you don't need $ sign before column letter.

In case of your situation:
[image]

Used `MIN` to find lowest value, `MAX` for largest value, `LARGE` for 2nd largest and used those as parameters for conditional formatting.

Note that you can use those formulas directly in conditional formatting, it is just easier to see what values will be selected if you want to use additional conditions such as AVERAGE and etc.
[image]

Comment: I've added a screenshot in my question for clarification.

Comment: Added additional example, logic is still same.

Comment: To clarify, those rules are applied only once for all columns selected.

Comment: Thanks. So in MAX(C6:C12), C6 and C12 are variable parameters because you did not add a $ sign right? And this allows you to find the max in each column, correct? It looks like it would be difficult to obtain the same gradient as I have in my example without writing a lot of additional formulas.

Comment: C6:C12 is a range where you want to find MAX value. Not adding $ (excel adds it automatically in some cases) means that for next column it will use D6:D12 so it will find separate max value for that exact column.

Comment: I tried applying your method but did not get satisfactory results https://imgur.com/a/hoLnrJl do you know where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: Try =MAX(A$1:A$8)